# How to return the given value from a key in a dictionary using MIT app inventor?

Tags: list, dictionary, iteration, app-inventor

I'm trying to develop an app using MIT app inventor which returns a specific integer based on certain conditions when a button is pressed.

Basically, I want to create a program that assigns users to specific rooms and assign that particular combination to an integer.

Firstly, the app creates two lists *user* = ["Dylan", "Fernando"] and *room* = ["A", "B", "C", "D"], and then another list *assigned* is created to assign both users to a random room. In this case, I hard coded the users to be assigned to particular rooms (i.e. "Dylan" , "A", "Fernando", "B").

After the assignment of rooms has been done, the app creates another list *combinations* that lists all possible combinations to the room assignments (i.e. 12 combinations).

A dictionary *combination* is then created to assign the key (combinations) to the value (integer). The app then iterates through the dictionary to find which combination matches the list *assigned* and returns the value (integer). And finally, another screen will pop up showing the integer returned by the code.

However, I am getting this error when I run the app, [image]

What am I doing wrong, please? This is my first time using this app inventor, so I am not really familiar with it.

Below is the code I have created.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Outstanding. Outstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Do you necessarily need the double quotes?
This works

[image]

let me recommend you to use **Do it** to debug your blocks, see also tip 4 here https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php
see also [Live Development, Testing, and Debugging Tools](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/testing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm still getting the same error: "The operation dictionary lookup cannot accept the arguments: ...". What does that mean?

Comment: @Kira Outstanding. Outstanding.

Comment: to find out, why you still get that error, a new screenshot of your relevant blocks would be required... btw. probably a better place to ask questions like this would be the App Inventor community https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/